# How to use STRAIGHT_JOIN with LINQ and Entity Framework - MySQL?

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, pomelo-entityframeworkcore-mysql

I am using Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql provider for MySQL and Entity Framework.

I have a complex dynamically generated query using LINQ and EF:

```
// Shortened for brevity
IQueryable<Account> accountQuery = db.Accounts.AsNoTracking()

foreach (var filter in filters)
{
     IQueryable<Account> subQuery = CreateSubQuery(filter);
     accountQuery = accountQuery.Where(aq => !subQuery.Select(a => a.Id).Contains(aq.Id));
}

accountQuery.Count(); // The slow part
```

Essentially the master query excludes all the account IDs in any of the subquerys.

If I run the raw query in SQL, it takes 2 minutes.  If the only thing I change is add STRAIGHT_JOIN to the raw query, it only takes a couple of seconds.  I guess it tells the optimizer to run the queries in order instead of trying to optimize.

So how can I add the equivalent of STRAIGHT_JOIN to the LINQ query...?

Comment: The last MySQL EF is better than Pomelo for my consideration. Really improved.

Comment: Could you describe briefly, why you have used such LINQ query? Maybe there is better solution.

Comment: Users have the ability to create filters that split the accounts up into different categories.  They also need the ability to show all the remaining accounts that don't fall into any of the filters, thus I loop over all the filters, and do a NOT IN (Select Id) for each filter.

Comment: @Leandro I am curious in what regards you think that Oracle's implementation is preferable over the Pomelo implementation. Anything concrete?

Comment: @MDave Please share a full sample LINQ query and the final generated SQL query from the same LINQ query with us. There is no official way to generate a `STRAIGHT_JOIN` in EF Core, but the LINQ query can likely be rewritten in a way that the `STRAIGHT_JOIN` isn't necessary at all (since this is just a helper construct to tell MySQL to change the table inclusion order). As a final resort, it is always possible to rewrite the actual SQL query.

Comment: @MDave Once you posted the requested code, I am happy to provide you with some possible solutions.

Comment: @Leandro Pomelo supports MySQL, MariaDB and Aurora, is faster than Oracles implementation, supports true async operations and has way more features including full spatial and JSON (both, Newtonsoft and Microsoft stacks) support. We usually answer within 24h to posted issues and are actively helping the community solving their individual problems. We are also in close contact with the EF Core team. I am the lead dev of the Pomelo project and we are constantly working on Pomelo, so if you got any feedback or questions, please feel encouraged to open an issue on our GitHub repo.

Comment: I understand your "commercial" position but Im using the official one with MariaDB and great performance (do you have any proof of this?) and of course, it's official. Maybe was needed in the past, great work but not now for me.  Thanks anyway.

Comment: @Leandro For performance tests, see https://mysqlconnector.net/. For common use cases, Oracle's implementation will usually work with MariaDB as well (though they implement only a subset of functionalities and over the years, MariaDB diverges in many details from MySQL, so users will encounter issues using Oracle's implementation with MariaDB, once they use less common features or functions). Pomelo is a 100% free open source and community driven project, with all contributors volunteering without financial compensation. It would still be interesting to us what concrete issues you encountered.

Comment: @Leandro Please report any concrete issues to https://github.com/PomeloFoundation/Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql/, so we can fix them. But if you are already using Oracle's implementation and are happy doing so, then there should be no need to switch to Pomelo. If you hit issues with Oracle's implementation in the future, you can always switch-out the libraries without much effort anyway.

Comment: @Thanks lauxjpn! I preciate your info! Actually so far so good and I'm afraid to migrate right now, but I'll do it if I encounter some problem with mine! :) Thanks again